# Firebase/auth chrome extension uses remote code and fails the Chrome Web Store checks

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, vite

The line of code ("firebase": "^9.22.1",)

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
```

Includes the following function in the build files.

```
_loadJS(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const el = document.createElement("script");
    el.setAttribute("src", url);
    el.onload = resolve;
    el.onerror = (e) => {
      const error = _createError("internal-error");
      error.customData = e;
      reject(error);
    };
    el.type = "text/javascript";
    el.charset = "UTF-8";
    getScriptParentElement().appendChild(el);
  });
}
```

And this goes against the Chrome web store policy where you can't execute remote code.

Has anyone run into this issue before? I don't want to have to remember to delete this function from the build every time I want to update the Chrome extension. I'm considering writing a Vite plugin to delete it from the build. Does anyone have any better options?

Update: I used Vite Plugin Replace to remove the illegal code. Is there a bundled Firebase optimized for Chrome extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same rejection from google.

[Violation(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKkcQ.png)

My steps:

1. Update firebase to `"firebase": "^10.8.0"`
2. Change import to `import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth/web-extension';`